# How can it be that I can't register on a website while my VPN is on

Tags: vpn, websites, registration

I've had problems with making a account on a website (https://etsy.com)
I tried different browsers, disabeling all my plugins with no succes.

I use a VPN service that automaticly turn on when I start my PC. My last deperate atempt was to turn my VPN of and that did the trick, I was able to register a account.

I find this very wierd, does someone have a explanation as to why this is?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the site that you were trying to connect to blocks VPNs.  There are many sites that do this - Netflix is one that is notorious for this.

It's fairly easy for sites to block VPN's, they just need to learn the blocks of IP addresses that VPN providers use to route their clients' connections through.

For more info, see https://www.howtogeek.com/403771/why-do-some-websites-block-vpns/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Etsy knows the IP addresses of popular VPN services and intentionally blocks them. A lot of places do this because otherwise, any user that they had to ban could trivially circumvent it by using a new VPN.